# Is it possible to perform a regex match on SYMBOL types in QuestDB?

Tags: regex, questdb

I am trying to perform a regex match on a symbol column:

```sql
SELECT * FROM my_table WHERE ~=(col_name, 'some.*')
```

This is not working for me, but I can't tell from the error if this is because I'm using unsupported match operators (`.*`), if the expression is not well formed for the query, or if it's even supported for the `SYMBOL` type at all. The error I get is

```
too few arguments for ‘~’ [found=0,expected=2]
```

Answer (score 1):

I made it work by removing the `=` after the `~`.

Here is the final command :

```
SELECT * FROM my_table WHERE ~(col_name, 'some.*')
```